# how to set type of progess timer in android cocos2d

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi am doing one app using cocos2d here i need to display set progress timer.i set using below code but i am not getting correct solution.

```
public class HelloWorldLayer extends CCColorLayer {
    static HelloWorldLayer layer;
      CGSize winSize;
     CCSprite home,target;
    protected HelloWorldLayer(ccColor4B color) {
    super(color);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    winSize = CCDirector.sharedDirector().displaySize();
    this.setIsTouchEnabled(true);

  CCSprite progressBorder=CCSprite.sprite("BorderImage.png");
           progressBorder.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(20, winSize.height - 50.5f));
           this.addChild(progressBorder);
           powerBar=CCProgressTimer.progress("Health.png");
           powerBar.setType(0);
           powerBar.setAnchorPoint(CGPoint.ccp(0, 0));
           powerBar.setPercentage(90);
           progressBorder.addChild(powerBar);
           this.schedule("gameLogic2", 1);

}

public static CCScene scene() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Creates scene  
    CCScene scene = CCScene.node();

    layer = new HelloWorldLayer(ccColor4B.ccc4(225, 225,225, 225));

    //adds layer to scene
    scene.addChild(layer);

    return scene;
}

          public void gameLogic2(float dt)
       {

       float sss=powerBar.getPercentage();

        sss +=1;
        powerBar.setPercentage(sss);
   }
```

in above code when powerbarpercentage 100 that time only helth image is dhowing other wise helth image is nit displaying.here i cant set timer type i think that is the problem if any one got idea about my problem please sove this...

Answer (score 0):

you just miss the type of powerBar in code.

Change code with

```
CCSprite progressBorder=CCSprite.sprite("BorderImage.png");
           progressBorder.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(20, winSize.height - 50.5f));
           this.addChild(progressBorder);
           powerBar=CCProgressTimer.progress("Health.png");
           progressBar.setType(CCProgressTimer.kCCProgressTimerTypeVerticalBarBT);
           powerBar.setAnchorPoint(CGPoint.ccp(0, 0));
           powerBar.setPercentage(90);
           progressBorder.addChild(powerBar);
           this.schedule("gameLogic2", 1);

}
```

Thanks